# How to get characters from a file and display on console?

Tags: c++, file, text-files, fstream, iostream

> I got this code from notes about file handling. From what I understand about this code, I want to get characters till x is reached in the file using this code. Why am I getting only the first character? If this code is incorrect, how should I alter the code to get characters till x is reached? Please help me understand this.<

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char a = '-';
    do
    {

        ifstream obj("test.txt", ifstream::in);// in would mean import from txt to ram
       // cout << obj << endl;
        if (obj.good() && a != obj.peek())
        {
            a = obj.getline();
            cout << a << endl;
        }
        obj.close();
    } while (a != 'x');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` is a `char`, it can only hold a single character. Further, you're opening and closing the file in each iteration of the loop, which means that you are reading the file from the beginning each time. Also, your code won't even compile, so I don't know where you got this from, or how you tried to use it...

Comment: @anastaciu sorry my bad, it was supposed to be a= obj.get().

Comment: Think about when and where you open and close the file.

Comment: @ChrisMM since the loop would terminate when a = x, shouldn't the whole line of text file before the character x be displayed?

Comment: @ChrisMM it did compile once. I made a text file by the name test and wrote "Hello x Hi" . Only H was displayed on the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a character and `std::getline()` returns an `istream`. Isn't there something wrong here? You cannot assign an `istream` to a `char`, so the code doesn't even compile.

You can simplify your code into this working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream obj("test.txt", ifstream::in);

    if (obj.good())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(obj, line))
        {
            for (auto& i : line)
            {
                if (i == 'x') return 0;
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    obj.close();
    return 0;
}
```

### test.txt:

```
This is
a
test fixle
```

### Output:

```
T
h
i
s

i
s
a
t
e
s
t

f
i
```

Comment: why is there a space after This and not after is, a and test?

Comment: Because there is no space between them in the file. `This is` is in one line and `test` is in another line.

Answer (score 2):

`obj.getline()` isn't valid. I see in your comments you meant to write `obj.get()`, so I'll stick with using that.

The main problem is that you are opening and closing the file within your `do-while` loop, which means that, for each iteration, you will open the file, read a character, then close the file. Each time you open the file, you actually start at the beginning, and thus you will not read until you get to an `'x'` character, but basically infinitely.

I didn't test this, but this seems to be what you want (comments added):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream obj("test.txt"); // open the file (no need to specify "in")
    if ( !obj ) { // check to see if the file could be opened
        std::cout << "Could not open file\n";
    } else {
        char a;
        while ( obj >> a ) { // while there's still something to read
            if ( a != 'x' ) { // if it's not an 'x' character, print it
                std::cout << a << std::endl;
            } else {
                break; // otherwise, break the loop
            }
        }
        obj.close(); // close the file
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is if(!obj) the same as if(obj.is_open())

Comment: More or less, yes. `if ( !obj )` checks if there's any errors in the stream, as opposed to just checking if it's open. In this context, it would be the same as `obj.is_open()` though. You can find more information [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!)

Comment: Oh, this makes sense! Thanks a lot for all the help!